# Why is Freya telling me I have no disk space left?

Tags: release-freya, files, system, disk-management

I installed Elementary OS Freya this morning, and I setup the partitions as follows:

- swaparea:    17GB
- /home   :    50GB
- /       :    50GB
- reserved bios boot thingy:    1024MB

And this is on a 128GB SSD.

So my problem is, why is Elementary OS Freya telling me that I am completely out of disk space? I have not installed anything *other than* the OS itself, and I left more than enough room on each partition.

---

This is really weird, and I hope someone can help shed some light on this.

---

`df -h` output:

```
me@me:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1        28G   26G  8.0K 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.5M  1.6G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.8G   92K  7.8G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   52K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb4       976M  3.4M  972M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb3        71G  139M   67G   1% /home
me@me:~$
```

Comment: Please add the output of the command `df -h` to your question.

Comment: @Rafael Just added output.

Comment: I don't understand. None of that even remotely matches what I entered as the values for each partition.

Comment: what is the output of `lsblk`?, also what did you use to create the partitions? the OS installer, gparted or fdisk?

Comment: I used the OS installer. I'll try that command when I get back to the PC later tonight.

Comment: Unless you have a whole bunch of apps installed, using 26 GB in / seems quite weird.

Comment: There isn't actually that much space being used anywhere. I am 99.99% sure that there is a bug that somehow causes it to misread disk info. I have not installed a single thing other than elementary OS. And elementary OS doesn't take up 28GB.

Comment: Same problem here. It looks like it's reading available space from /run/user instead of /

Answer (score 2):

The best possible thing I can think of is 'your options did not save' at the time of partitioning and the installer somehow pointed to system defaults. Did you really save your partition settings before proceeding (and did not do back/forward clicks)?

Comment: This is what I am thinking. I have tried formatting and repartitioning and reinstalling from scratch several times with no success. I think it's a bug in Ubuntu based distros. I had this problem with Ubuntu 15.04 and 14.04. I don't have this issue with Fedora though. And for some reason, Ubuntu and EOS aren't detecting my second internal hard drive.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 based elementary OS and it works smoothly

Comment: I meant compatibility bugs, with respect to my particular hardware. I should have said that actually, but I am a lazy typer.

Comment: By *not detecting* do you mean they are not showing up in a file manager or from `sudo fdisk -l`? In your examples above you list /dev/sdb, so it appears to me Linux is certainly detecting at least 2 drives. Is there any mention of another drive (sdc?) in `dmesg` at all? What is the model of hdd? Is it connected via a RAID controller per chance (not necessarily enabled, just connected to)?

Comment: I am glad its working foe you, Kajal. I havent got it working yet, but I have had to switch back to Windows temporarily so i can finish my project. I havr made some progress with elementaty though booting with 'forcevideo' sonehow resolves many issues i was having, includong the partman errors.